# Month abbreviation in Wordpress Archives Widget

Tags: wordpress, archive, abbreviation

I've been trying for 3 straight days with no luck to make the archives widget display the months in their abbreviated form that are included in locale.php
So far I'm down to this piece of code where the month names originate in general-template.php:

```
    if ( $arcresults ) {
        $afterafter = $after;
        foreach ( (array) $arcresults as $arcresult ) {
            $url = get_month_link( $arcresult->year, $arcresult->month );
            /* translators: 1: month name, 2: 4-digit year */
            $text = sprintf(__('%1$s %2$d'), $wp_locale->get_month($arcresult->month), $arcresult->year);
            if ( $show_post_count )
                $after = '&nbsp;('.$arcresult->posts.')' . $afterafter;
            $output .= get_archives_link($url, $text, $format, $before, $after);
        }
```

I did find in the same file where the calendar widget originates the abbreviated months. But with my limited knowledge I haven't been able to adapt it to the archives:

```
if ( $previous ) {
    $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="prev"><a href="' . get_month_link($previous->year, $previous->month) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf(__('View posts for %1$s %2$s'), $wp_locale->get_month($previous->month), date('Y', mktime(0, 0 , 0, $previous->month, 1, $previous->year)))) . '">&laquo; ' . $wp_locale->get_month_abbrev($wp_locale->get_month($previous->month)) . '</a></td>';
} else {
    $calendar_output .= "\n\t\t".'<td colspan="3" id="prev" class="pad">&nbsp;</td>';
}
```

Can anyone please give me some tips or help me use the get_month_abbrev function to work in the archives?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So a friend helped me crack this.

Go into general-template.php and

replace:

```
            $text = sprintf(__('%1$s %2$d'), $wp_locale->get_month($arcresult->month), $arcresult->year);
```

with:

```
            $text = sprintf(__('%1$s %2$d'), $wp_locale->get_month_abbrev($wp_locale->get_month($arcresult->month)), $arcresult->year);
```

Thanks everyone.. Hope it helps more people out there.

(in Wordpress 3.5.1, the filepath is: 'wordpress\wp-includes\general-template.php' and this string is on line 937)